# indefinite cookies set

Tags: java, http, servlets, cookies

I want to know can we set the cookies for the indefinite period of time. I mean to say which lasts for a life-long. If yes, then how?

I am aware that we can set the MaxAge of cookies of the limited years if we wish..

I am asking about this with respect to the cookies...Is there any advanced servlet feature which allows to set the cookies for life-long. I want to use it to count every visit of the user on that particular site. How can i do that please guide me..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option. But you can set it to expire in 20 years, which should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks..so there is no such option.

Comment: For what purpose then sessionbind and sessionlistener are used??

Comment: for a completely different purpose :) You can check their javadocs, and if not clear - ask another question